# did SO Javascript libs changed domains?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I've been having a problem using StackOverflow.com recently, i am not able to submit comments or upvote answers.

I am behind a firewall that has an exception for the stackoverflow domain.

I didnt have this problem before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow is now using Google's hosted JQuery files. Try clearing your cache and restarting your browser. Also, if you're at work, it's possible (but unlikely) that your employer is blocking Google.

Comment: My cache was still looking for the files in the old domain, and also my employer is blocking the new domain (its not google.com but another one)

Answer (score 1):

Probably related to Kyles's answer, I recently made a setup change to allow JavaScripts from googleapis.com in addition to the ones StackOverflow was requesting previously: stackoverflow.com, quantserve.com and google-analytics.com. You need to allow JavaScripts from stackoverflow.com and googleapis.com for full user functionality and [following the advice in Jeff's comment] from quantserve.com and google-analytics.com for SO's statistics tracking.

**Edit**

In mid-August 2009, an exception for sstatic.net was also required (? for openid login page).

Comment: you don't have to allow quantserve or google-analytics -- those are just for statistics tracking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have firebug. Open it up and enable the Net section. See if any files are red (not found) when you load up a page on SO.